# The Event is not genrated with Track Event in Google Analytycs

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I am generating the Event tracking in Google analytic. but i can not see the event is generated with in Behavior link -> Events -> Overview.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-46891304-1']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

        (function () {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'ProfileMenu', 'MenuClick', '', 1]);

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is for Tracking Event..!!!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach the event tracking script on to a event listener.

Your event tracking code does not seem to be attached to anything.

For example if I wanted to track a button click this is how I would write it with jQuery.

**html**

```
<button id='button1'>Button<button>
```

**JavaScript/jQuery**

```
$('#button1').click(function(){
 //fires the event tracking method when button is clicked.    
 _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Category', 'Action', 'Opt Label', Opt Value, 'Opt non-interaction'])
})
```

Here is all the documentation https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21520268/how-to-record-every-moment-in-google-analytics/21534107?noredirect=1#comment32537393_21534107) is a post that I went in more in depth into event tracking.

Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Hi, I thin the issue was 24 hours with Event viewr, before 4 -5 hours i can see all the 222 events from yesterday to today, but currently i can see only 106 events of todays only, why it had been removed?

Comment: I can not see yesterays events in Google Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

It takes 24 hours for data to be processed. Before that time you should be able to see your events in the Real-time reports under

```
Real-time -> events.
```

after 24 hours has passed the data should show up under.

```
Behavior link -> Events -> Overview.
```